# How to ease between two y-coordinates?

Tags: javascript, canvas, coordinates, easing

For a school assignment we have to make a graph in Javascript. 
The teacher would like to see some animated graphs. So I build a graph about my Tweets in one week, but cannot find how to ease between two y-coordinates.

You can find my project [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/co4otmn7/), or [on this website](http://www.student.howest.be/jonas.leupe/20142015/CP).

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var data = [];
var huidigeYpos = [];
var nieuweYpos = [];
var count = [];
var snelheid = 0;

function init(){
    ctx.fillStyle="rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.translate(0, 445);

    for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        data[i] = form[i].value*30;
    }

    draw();
}

function draw(){
    ctx.fillStyle="rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,-canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();    
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    for(var i = 0; i <= 750; i += 125){
        ctx.lineTo(i,-data[i/125]);
        huidigeYpos.push((data[i/125]));
    }
    if(huidigeYpos.length > 7){
        huidigeYpos.splice(0, 7);
    }
    ctx.lineTo(750,0);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle="#0084FF";    
    ctx.fill();
}

function invullen(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        data[i] = form[i].value*30;
    }
    draw();
}

function drawRandomGraph(){ 

    for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        form[i].value = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
        nieuweYpos.push(form[i].value*30);
    }
    if(nieuweYpos.length > 7){
        nieuweYpos.splice(0, 7);
    }
    invullen();
}

init();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you further explain your problem? ...

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM.
I woud like to know how to make a easing effect when the values are changing. Like when I press the drawRandomGraph button, the old values ease to the new values and displayed.

Comment: first: efect (animation), for this is better to use a library, for example ds3 [http://d3js.org/](http://d3js.org/) [ds3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/33a9e350516da54a5d4f)

Comment: second: to add tag `canvas` a your question

Comment: third: button, I answer in post

Comment: Robert Penner has done some research with easing functions for JavaScript/ActionScript. Take a look at his collection here: http://robertpenner.com/easing/. The jQuery easing plugin uses his algorithms (http://easings.net/).

Answer (score 14):

You can use interpolation in combination with a easing-function. Standard interpolation between two points, aka lerping, is simple enough:

```
p = p1 + (p2 - p1) * t
```

where `t` is in the range [0, 1]

By injecting a easing-function for `t`, which also is in the [0, 1] range, you can ease the transition:

```
...
y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * easeInOut(t);
...

function easeInOut(t) {return t<.5 ? 4*t*t*t : (t-1)*(2*t-2)*(2*t-2)+1}
```

There are several [variations](http://easings.net/) of easing functions, the above is cubic. You can find more [here](https://github.com/danro/easing-js/blob/master/easing.js) as well as the popular [Penner](http://robertpenner.com/easing/) versions.

For your case you would just update `y2` with the new target value as use the old `y2` as `y1`, then lerp/ease between them for each x point using the same `t` value.

The demo below shows how to use these, integrate as you want.

## Example

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    y1 = 10, y2 = 140,                   // source and destination positions
    current = 0, max = 50, delta = 1;    // counters for calculating/animating t

(function loop() {

  // calc t
  current += delta;
  var t = current / max;                 // normalize so we get [0, 1]
  if (t <= 0 || t >= 1) delta = -delta;  // to ping-pong the animation for demo
  
  // calc lerp linear
  var yl = lerp(y1, y2, t),              // linear
      ye = lerp(y1, y2, easeInOut(t));   // with easing
  
  // draw some graphics to show (linear : easing)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(20, yl - 10, 20, 20);
  ctx.fillRect(50, ye - 10, 20, 20);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();

function lerp(p1, p2, t) {
  return p1 + (p2 - p1) * t
}

function easeInOut(t) {
  return t<.5 ? 4*t*t*t : (t-1)*(2*t-2)*(2*t-2)+1
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```